# File download speed windows server 2003 over long distance

Tags: iis-6, network-speed

The company I'm working for currently has a server situated in Hong Kong, serving content to mobile phone user OTA via their operator's APN, mainly to operators from the south east asia region.

We adopted the OMA OTA provisioning approach such that we only count a download being successful when we received a 900 Success from the Install-Notify response, otherwise count as download failure.

However, there are tonnes of errors including 907 Invalid JAR, 902 Loss of service, etc.  I am talking about an error ratio of 97%.  I have went thru the code path and examined the content of the JAD, JAR and the manifest file are valid.

I start suspecting the high number of errors is due to the pathway from our server to the destination being too convoluted.

I tried `tracert` from the server (windows server 2003 R2) to the designated APN and found out it is essentially going thru Japan and US and didn't managed to get all hops within the limit of 30.

Is there anything I can do to be more certain that the high number of download failures are due to the geographical distance rather than anything.  Having said that we have performed UAT test for end-to-end within Hong Kong however that doesn't imply things would work the same outside the region.

We are using IIS6 with ASP.NET2.0, the server is sitting on a network backbone from a data center where I know they have a high speed link to Japan.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance is not an excuse. Most of us work over 20'000km links without problems (except annoying ping). I would really try to move server closer to the users, or at least try to use different datacenter in HK.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion BarsMonster.
Now I need to gather some real evidence to present to the boss to support a datacentre move.